# javascript scroll to active sidemenu item on map marker click

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox-gl-js

Based on the [example from mapbox store locator](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/building-a-store-locator/) whenever a marker or sidemenu item is selected it has the 'active' class. The  item is then highlighted in the sidebar but sometimes when the item selected is out of view, you have to scroll down the menu to see the active item. Is it possible to automatically scroll to the active class item? Bringing the active item to the top of the list would work as well! Any help would be appreciated. Is it possible? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset='utf-8' />
      <title>Store Locator</title>
      <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700' rel='stylesheet'>
      <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.52.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
      <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.52.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

      <style>

        body {
          color:#404040;
          font:400 15px/22px 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', Sans-serif;
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
          -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
        }

        * {
          -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
          -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
          box-sizing:border-box;
        }

        .sidebar {
          position:absolute;
          width:33.3333%;
          height:100%;
          top:0;left:0;
          overflow:hidden;
          border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        }
        .pad2 {
          padding:20px;
        }

        .map {
          position:absolute;
          left:33.3333%;
          width:66.6666%;
          top:0;bottom:0;
        }

        h1 {
          font-size:22px;
          margin:0;
          font-weight:400;
          line-height: 20px;
          padding: 20px 2px;
        }

        a {
          color:#404040;
          text-decoration:none;
        }

        a:hover {
          color:#101010;
        }

        .heading {
          background:#fff;
          border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
          min-height:60px;
          line-height:60px;
          padding:0 10px;
          background-color: #00853e;
          color: #fff;
        }

        .listings {
          height:100%;
          overflow:auto;
          padding-bottom:60px;
        }

        .listings .item {
          display:block;
          border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
          padding:10px;
          text-decoration:none;
        }

        .listings .item:last-child { border-bottom:none; }
        .listings .item .title {
          display:block;
          color:#00853e;
          font-weight:700;
        }

        .listings .item .title small { font-weight:400; }
        .listings .item.active .title,
        .listings .item .title:hover { color:#8cc63f; }
        .listings .item.active {
          background-color:#f8f8f8;
        }
        ::-webkit-scrollbar {
          width:3px;
          height:3px;
          border-left:0;
          background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        }
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
          background:none;
        }
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
          background:#00853e;
          border-radius:0;
        }

        .marker {
          border: none;
          cursor: pointer;
          height: 56px;
          width: 56px;
          background-image: url(marker.png);
          background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        .clearfix { display:block; }
        .clearfix:after {
          content:'.';
          display:block;
          height:0;
          clear:both;
          visibility:hidden;
        }

        /* Marker tweaks */
        .mapboxgl-popup {
          padding-bottom: 50px;
        }

        .mapboxgl-popup-close-button {
          display:none;
        }
        .mapboxgl-popup-content {
          font:400 15px/22px 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', Sans-serif;
          padding:0;
          width:180px;
        }
        .mapboxgl-popup-content-wrapper {
          padding:1%;
        }
        .mapboxgl-popup-content h3 {
          background:#91c949;
          color:#fff;
          margin:0;
          display:block;
          padding:10px;
          border-radius:3px 3px 0 0;
          font-weight:700;
          margin-top:-15px;
        }

        .mapboxgl-popup-content h4 {
          margin:0;
          display:block;
          padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
          font-weight:400;
        }

        .mapboxgl-popup-content div {
          padding:10px;
        }

        .mapboxgl-container .leaflet-marker-icon {
          cursor:pointer;
        }

        .mapboxgl-popup-anchor-top > .mapboxgl-popup-content {
          margin-top: 15px;
        }

        .mapboxgl-popup-anchor-top > .mapboxgl-popup-tip {
          border-bottom-color: #91c949;
        }
      </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class='sidebar'>
      <div class='heading'>
        <h1>Our locations</h1>
      </div>
    <div id='listings' class='listings'></div>
    </div>
    <div id='map' class='map'> </div>

  <script>
  // This will let you use the .remove() function later on
  if (!('remove' in Element.prototype)) {
    Element.prototype.remove = function() {
      if (this.parentNode) {
          this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
      }
    };
  }

  mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZXhhbXBsZXMiLCJhIjoiY2lqbmpqazdlMDBsdnRva284cWd3bm11byJ9.V6Hg2oYJwMAxeoR9GEzkAA';

  // This adds the map
  var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    // container id specified in the HTML
    container: 'map',
    // style URL
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
    // initial position in [long, lat] format
    center: [-77.034084142948, 38.909671288923],
    // initial zoom
    zoom: 13,
    scrollZoom: false
  });

  var stores = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -77.034084142948,
            38.909671288923
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "phoneFormatted": "(202) 234-7336",
          "phone": "2022347336",
          "address": "1471 P St NW",
          "city": "Washington DC",
          "country": "United States",
          "crossStreet": "at 15th St NW",
          "postalCode": "20005",
          "state": "D.C."
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -77.049766,
            38.900772
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "phoneFormatted": "(202) 507-8357",
          "phone": "2025078357",
          "address": "2221 I St NW",
          "city": "Washington DC",
          "country": "United States",
          "crossStreet": "at 22nd St NW",
          "postalCode": "20037",
          "state": "D.C."
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -77.043929,
            38.910525
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "phoneFormatted": "(202) 387-9338",
          "phone": "2023879338",
          "address": "1512 Connecticut Ave NW",
          "city": "Washington DC",
          "country": "United States",
          "crossStreet": "at Dupont Circle",
          "postalCode": "20036",
          "state": "D.C."
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -77.0672,
            38.90516896
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "phoneFormatted": "(202) 337-9338",
          "phone": "2023379338",
          "address": "3333 M St NW",
          "city": "Washington DC",
          "country": "United States",
          "crossStreet": "at 34th St NW",
          "postalCode": "20007",
          "state": "D.C."
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -77.002583742142,
            38.887041080933
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "phoneFormatted": "(202) 547-9338",
          "phone": "2025479338",
          "address": "221 Pennsylvania Ave SE",
          "city": "Washington DC",
          "country": "United States",
          "crossStreet": "btwn 2nd & 3rd Sts. SE",
          "postalCode": "20003",
          "state": "D.C."
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -76.933492720127,
            38.99225245786
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "address": "8204 Baltimore Ave",
          "city": "College Park",
          "country": "United States",
          "postalCode": "20740",
          "state": "MD"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -77.097083330154,
            38.980979
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "phoneFormatted": "(301) 654-7336",
          "phone": "3016547336",
          "address": "4831 Bethesda Ave",
          "cc": "US",
          "city": "Bethesda",
          "country": "United States",
          "postalCode": "20814",
          "state": "MD"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -77.359425054188,
            38.958058116661
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "phoneFormatted": "(571) 203-0082",
          "phone": "5712030082",
          "address": "11935 Democracy Dr",
          "city": "Reston",
          "country": "United States",
          "crossStreet": "btw Explorer & Library",
          "postalCode": "20190",
          "state": "VA"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -77.10853099823,
            38.880100922392
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "phoneFormatted": "(703) 522-2016",
          "phone": "7035222016",
          "address": "4075 Wilson Blvd",
          "city": "Arlington",
          "country": "United States",
          "crossStreet": "at N Randolph St.",
          "postalCode": "22203",
          "state": "VA"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -75.28784,
            40.008008
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "phoneFormatted": "(610) 642-9400",
          "phone": "6106429400",
          "address": "68 Coulter Ave",
          "city": "Ardmore",
          "country": "United States",
          "postalCode": "19003",
          "state": "PA"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -75.20121216774,
            39.954030175164
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "phoneFormatted": "(215) 386-1365",
          "phone": "2153861365",
          "address": "3925 Walnut St",
          "city": "Philadelphia",
          "country": "United States",
          "postalCode": "19104",
          "state": "PA"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -77.043959498405,
            38.903883387232
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "phoneFormatted": "(202) 331-3355",
          "phone": "2023313355",
          "address": "1901 L St. NW",
          "city": "Washington DC",
          "country": "United States",
          "crossStreet": "at 19th St",
          "postalCode": "20036",
          "state": "D.C."
        }
      }]
    };
  // This adds the data to the map
  map.on('load', function (e) {
    // This is where your '.addLayer()' used to be, instead add only the source without styling a layer
    map.addSource("places", {
      "type": "geojson",
      "data": stores
    });
    // Initialize the list
    buildLocationList(stores);

  });

  // This is where your interactions with the symbol layer used to be
  // Now you have interactions with DOM markers instead
  stores.features.forEach(function(marker, i) {
    // Create an img element for the marker
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.id = "marker-" + i;
    el.className = 'marker';
    // Add markers to the map at all points
    new mapboxgl.Marker(el, {offset: [0, -23]})
        .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
        .addTo(map);

    el.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        // 1. Fly to the point
        flyToStore(marker);

        // 2. Close all other popups and display popup for clicked store
        createPopUp(marker);

        // 3. Highlight listing in sidebar (and remove highlight for all other listings)
        var activeItem = document.getElementsByClassName('active');

        e.stopPropagation();
        if (activeItem[0]) {
           activeItem[0].classList.remove('active');
        }

        var listing = document.getElementById('listing-' + i);
        listing.classList.add('active');

       //TODO: Scroll sidemenu to active item or bring it to the top           
    });
  });


  function flyToStore(currentFeature) {
    map.flyTo({
        center: currentFeature.geometry.coordinates,
        zoom: 15
      });
  }

  function createPopUp(currentFeature) {
    var popUps = document.getElementsByClassName('mapboxgl-popup');
    if (popUps[0]) popUps[0].remove();


    var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({closeOnClick: false})
          .setLngLat(currentFeature.geometry.coordinates)
          .setHTML('<h3>Sweetgreen</h3>' +
            '<h4>' + currentFeature.properties.address + '</h4>')
          .addTo(map);
  }


  function buildLocationList(data) {
    for (i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
      var currentFeature = data.features[i];
      var prop = currentFeature.properties;

      var listings = document.getElementById('listings');
      var listing = listings.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
      listing.className = 'item';
      listing.id = "listing-" + i;

      var link = listing.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
      link.href = '#';
      link.className = 'title';
      link.dataPosition = i;
      link.innerHTML = prop.address;

      var details = listing.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
      details.innerHTML = prop.city;
      if (prop.phone) {
        details.innerHTML += ' &middot; ' + prop.phoneFormatted;
      }



      link.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        // Update the currentFeature to the store associated with the clicked link
        var clickedListing = data.features[this.dataPosition];

        // 1. Fly to the point
        flyToStore(clickedListing);

        // 2. Close all other popups and display popup for clicked store
        createPopUp(clickedListing);

        // 3. Highlight listing in sidebar (and remove highlight for all other listings)
        var activeItem = document.getElementsByClassName('active');

        if (activeItem[0]) {
           activeItem[0].classList.remove('active');
        }
        this.parentNode.classList.add('active');

      });
    }
  }


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just had to use:

```
listing.scrollIntoView();
```